# Same parameters name in Web API URL Routes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am wondering if its possible to use the same parameter name in URL routes using ASP.NET WebAPI.

For example

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userid}")]

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userid}/customers")]

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userid}/orders")]
```

When i have the routes set up like this i get an error saying there are multiple actions for this request. However

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userid}")]

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userid2}/customers")]

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{userid3}/orders")]
```

works.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Please try by changing the route from-

    [Route("{userid}/orders")]

to 

 [HttpGet]
    [Route("orders/{userid}")]

Comment: Id prefer to leave the URL how they are if possible